# Adjusting the plot axis range and intervals

Tags: plot, axis

I am new to 'R' but have started to produce some useful plots. My query is how do I adjust the range and intervals on both axes?

In the example shown, the first issue is the X axis is showing test number values that are not integers; so test value 2.5 does not make any sense and instead, I need to have say 2,4,6,8,10,12, or a grid line at each value from 1 to 12.

For the Y axis, if I wanted a bit more space above and below the points, how can I adjust the scale range from say 0.5 - 2.0 instead of 1.2 - 1.8?

I'm finding the vast array of possible coding a bit dizzying.

[image]

Here is the code :

```
SOH1 %>% ggplot(aes(Test.No.,MJ, color = MJ))
+geom_point(size=3,alpha=0.7)+ geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F)
```

Thanks

Julian

Comment: Can you share you code for the plot as well?

Comment: SOH1 %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Test.No.,MJ, color = MJ))+geom_point(size=3,alpha=0.7)+
  geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you need to use `xlim()` and `ylim()` methods.

For `xlim()` you need to pass two numeric values, specifying the left and the
right values of your desired interval.

For `ylim()` you need to pass two numeric values, specifying the lower and the upper values of your desired interval.

One way is to append these methods to the end of your code :

```
SOH1 %>% ggplot(aes(Test.No.,MJ, color = MJ))+
geom_point(size=3,alpha=0.7)+ geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F)+
xlim(1,12) + ylim(0.5,2)
```

Updated Answer :

If you want to set the breaking number manually, you can use `scale_x_continuous()` instead of `xlim()`. You need to pass the desired breaks as an array to this function. for example :

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12))
```

So after changing the code, it will be like :

```
SOH1 %>% ggplot(aes(Test.No.,MJ, color = MJ))+
geom_point(size=3,alpha=0.7)+ geom_smooth(method=lm,se=F)+
scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,2,4,6,8,10,12)) + ylim(0.5,2)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. That has addressed the Y axis but what about the X axis? I need the increments to be 0,1,2,3,4 etc or 0,2,4,6,8 etc as test no 2.5 has no meaning. This is where the interval needs to be set at an integer; if possible. I would have thought the xlim (1,12) would have done it and where the '1' was the increment but it hasn't changed.

Comment: Add an image of the resulted plot so that I can see what is changed.

Comment: How do I add the plot image to a comment? Use ImgBB? Here goes: https://i.ibb.co/XLKhYFY/Rplot.png

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/D4GTPks/Rplot01.png

Comment: The data points vanished for a while but have returned.

Comment: I don't know how to do either of those. Do you mean to indicate it as being fully answered?